# How does boost::variant store references?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

The following code compiles and does the "right thing" :

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  boost::variant<int&, float&> x = a;
  a = 20;
  std::cout << boost::get<int&>(x) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

How does boost::variant store a reference? According to C++ standard, how references are stored is completely up to the compiler. Actually, how does `boost::variant` even know how many bytes is taken up by a reference? `sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T)`, so it can't be using `sizeof()` operator. Now, I know references are most probably implemented as pointers, but there is no guarantee in the language. A good explanation of how `get<>` and visitation works when the variant is storing references get extra points :)

Comment: By wrapping them in an object. `<< sizeof(std::vector<char>&), sizeof(std::vector<char>), sizeof(T); struct T { std::vector<char>& r; };` 56, 56, 8

Answer (score 7):

You can declare struct fields as references.

```
struct ref_to_int {
    ref_to_int(int& init)
      : _storage(init) {} // _storage stores the reference.
private:
    int& _storage;
};
```

You can take the `sizeof(ref_to_int)`, which is `8` on my x64 with gcc. The field stores the reference.